# Question about Bernoulli trials.

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve the following problem. A shooter shots at a target, once he hits the target the competition stops and he counts his remaining bullets. What is the probability that he is left with at least one bullet if he started with 10. The probability to hit the target is 0.2.

Here is my thinking:
The 'at least one' suggests using complementary probability. So let's consider the probability $P_1$ of spending all the bullets
$$P_1=(1-0.2)^{10}+0.2(1-0.2)^9.$$
Therefore, the probability $P_2$ of saving at least one bullet should be 
$$P_2=1-P_1\approx0.865782272$$
It should be also possible to express $P_2$ by counting individual cases, say one hit (0.2), miss followed by a hit (0.8*0.2), two misses and a hit $(0.8^2*0.2)$ etc. This can be expressed using the formula:
$$P_2=0.2\sum_{x=0}^80.8^x\approx0.865782272$$
Unfortunately, this is wrong and clearly there is something wrong with my solution. According to the book the answer is $0.376$.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you considering that the game stops when he hits the target? So the possibilities are only H, MH, MMH, MMMH...

Comment: Yes, game over after the first hit.

Comment: It looks to me like your solution is correct. Are you sure about the book's solution? The probability you want is the probability that the first hit happens within the first 9 shots, which is just the CDF of a geometric random variable with $p=0.2$

Comment: The shooter will have no bullets left precisely if the shooter misses the first $9$ times. The probability of this is $(0.8)^9$.

Comment: So, shot number 10 doesn’t matter?

Comment: No, you exhaust all bullets with the 10th shot anyway, if you have already used up 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your reasoning.  The shooter spends all bullets if and only if (a) all $10$ shots miss, or (b) the first $9$ shots miss, and the final shot hits.  As each shot is an independent Bernoulli trial, the  random number of shots fired $X$ is a right-censored geometric random variable with probability of success $p = 0.2$; i.e., $$\Pr[X = x] = \begin{cases} (1-p)^{x-1} p, & x = 1, 2, \ldots, 9, \\ (1-p)^9, & x = 10. \end{cases}$$  The case where $X = 10$ can be intuitively understood by seeing that if the shooter fails on the first $9$ tries, the last bullet is always spent, and the outcome of that final try (success or failure) is irrelevant--there will be no bullets left.  Hence the probability $$\Pr[X \ne 10] = \Pr[X \le 9] = 1 - (1-p)^9.$$  So unless there was some subtlety of the wording or interpretation of the question that we have missed, I see no reason to dispute your solution.

Comment: I found wrong answers in this book already in the past, therefore I can't rule out the possibility. Actually, the original text is in German, but after reading it few times I don't think that there is any subtlety of the wording.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer, and all the others are correct.
But you should always try to find the simplest solution, which has been outlined by André in his comment.

If you miss 9 times, you will exhaust all bullets whether you hit or miss on the 10th,

thus taking its complement, $Pr = 1 - 0.8^9$

Comment: I think that in this case my answer is not entirely correct, because I am also considering the outcome of the 10th, which is not actually needed.

Comment: Your ans is correct, but done in a roundabout way, P1 counts [failing on  10 trials] + [failing on the 1st 9 and succeeding on the 10th]

Answer (score 0):

The event you should consider is 'no bullets left'. Find its probability and take the complement of it.

Comment: could the downvoter elaborate pls?

Comment: Added +1 to compensate for unwarranted downvote.